# WSL2 & tmux: Pasting Windows clipboard with right click

Tags: tmux

I am trying to get "normal" copy-and-paste behavior in `tmux` running under WSL2.

I managed to enable copying from `tmux` to the clipboard using the plugin `tmux-yank`, which internally uses `clip.exe`.

I am missing the opposite direction, i.e. pasting the current content of the clipboard using right-click.
I found some solutions for X systems that are based on `xclip`, which of course do not work in WSL2.
It seems that some program that does the opposite of `clip.exe`, i.e. printing out the current clipboard content, is missing (`paste.exe`?).

Has anybody solved this problem?

Comment: Did you try <Shift>+<Insert>? I vaguely remember this to work for Windows terminal work (cygwin and the like).